# Throws error when "new CouchDB.Database(queueDb);" for the second time

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, couchdb, cloudant

I am using meteor-couchdb and trying to connect to db when an API call is made and perform the required operation.

```
dbName = new CouchDB.Database('db_name');
```

But when API call is made again it throws below error

```
Error: A method named '/db_name/insert' is already defined
```

Depending on the API call, I should be able to select the Db it need to be connected.
I tried doing in node way i.e

```
Cloudant.use('db_name');
```

But then as Meteor is my server side framework I need to handle async function in synchronously using async await or Meteor.wrapAsync().

What would be the suggested approach to connect to db and perform the actions, whenever an API call is made ?

Comment: You should call `dbName = new CouchDB.Database('db_name');` only once and reuse the connection instead of creating a new one. You also save a few miliseconds since you don't need to create new connection every time there's an api call. Node.js apps are usualy long running processes so persistent connection makes a lot of sense.

Comment: But I need to connect to different cloudant dbs based on the API calls.
Should I be connecting to all dbs when meteor starts ? In that case, if a new DB is added, how will meteor gets the instance of newly created DB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand the meteor CouchDB implementation correctly it connects to one db server and allows you to work with multiple databases so there's essentialy one single connection to the server no matter how many times you call `new CouchDB.Database('db_name');`

What you should do is following:

```
// tasks.js
// create an instance of Tasks database only once 
var Tasks = new CouchDB.Database('tasks');
// you may want to export it so you can use it elsewhere
exports.Tasks = Tasks;

// blabla.js
// in another file require the file
var Tasks = require('path/to/tasks.js').Tasks;
// and use it when needed
Tasks.find();
```

**Additional code to answer the comment bellow**

You could have a file let's call it `dbs.js` that would handle dynamic creation of dbs for you

```
var dbs = {};

exports.getDb = function(name){
    if (!dbs[name])
        dbs[name] = new CouchDB.Database(name);

    return dbs[name];
};
```

then use this anywhere you want

```
var Tasks = require('dbs.js').getDb('Tasks');
Tasks.find();
```

Comment: Yes, you understood it right.
But If I have 100 dbs like 'tasks' then I can not write 100 such files.
If we can list all the dbs  from a particular cloudant account and connect to it while initialising meteor server, even then dynamically created dbs wont be listed. I may have to stop the server and restart everytime I add a new DB or I should have a watch on Cloudant which updates the db list.

Comment: @AnnopGoudar i have added code for dynamic creation of dbs. Hope it helps.

Comment: But this fails when you call new CouchDB.Database(dbname); for the second time, if dbname is same. And results to below error
Error: A method named '/db_name/insert' is already defined

Comment: Why would you call `new CouchDB.Database` second time? By using `require('dbs.js').getDb('Tasks')` you create the database instance if this is the first time you are calling it or return already existing instance.